# How to show $rank(BA)=rank(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field and let $A_{m\times n}$ $B_{m\times m}$
given that $rank(B)=m$ show that $$rank(BA)=rank(A)$$

I guess the idea is to use the equality $$dim(N(A))=n-rank(A)$$

so I understand from the given that $dim(N(B))=0$  and I dont understand how to procced from here, how does this given is helping me? I assume i need to show some how that $dim(N(BA))=dim(N(A))$

Comment: You can show the latter by arguing these null spaces are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hnt: The linear mappings $x\mapsto Ax$ and $x\mapsto BAx$ have the same kernel as $B$ is invertible by the rank condition and so in your terminology $\dim(N(A)) = \dim(N(BA))$.

Answer (score 2):

$A_{m\times n}$ And $B_{m\times m}$ and $rank(B) =m$

Then, $N(A) =N(BA) $

$v\in N(B) \implies Bv=0$

Now, $(BA)v=B(Av) =B\cdot0=0$

$\implies v\in N(BA) $

Hence, $N(B) \subseteq N(BA) $

Again,$v\in N(BA) \implies (BA) v=0$

As $B_{m\times m}$ is Invertible.

$Av=B^{-1}\cdot 0=0$

$\implies v\in N(A) $

$\implies N(BA) \subseteq N(A) $

Hence $N(BA) =N(B) $

Now, using rank-nullity theorem,

$Null(BA) + Rank(BA) =m=Null(A) +Rank(A) $

Comment: Nice approach. How do I handle the oposite case? if now $B$ is $n\times n$  invertible matrix. how do I show that $rank(AB)=rank(A)$